# Playing youtube videos through intent

Tags: java, android, youtube

How do i make an intent open an youtube video?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have some use for this youtube API for java, I didn't have time to use it myself yet but i think this is what you need.

[Youtube API](http://code.google.com/intl/da-DK/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_audience.html)

Answer (score 1):

Do that:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
              Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoid")));
```

Your video will open on youtube application if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Just throw a normal VIEW intent with the video URL in it. If installed, the Youtube app will handle the intend. If not, the normal browser will do.